# Filtrar un array de objetos aninado

Tags: javascript, array, objeto

tengo la siguiente duda y quisera me comentaran si es posible encontrar una solución más pro

```
[{
  id: 1
  name: nombre 
    prices: [
      {
        id: 1,
        amount: 300
        end_date: "2021-10-01"
        start_date: "2021-10-10"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        amount: 700
        end_date: "2021-10-11"
        start_date: "2021-10-15"
      }
    ]
  },
  ...
  ...
]
```

lo que necesito obtener un array con los elementos donde el amount en el array prices sea igual a 300

la solución que encontré fue la siguiente

```
get filteredLocalTax () {
  if (this.hotelDetail) {
    return this.hotelDetail.local_taxes.filter(item => {
    item.prices = item.prices.filter(p => p.amount === 300)
    return item.prices.length
    })
  }
  return null
}
```

pero no me gusta, porque modifica el array original (item.prices = item.prices.filter(p => p.amount === 300)), claro, también tengo la opción de hacer una copia al array original...

mi pregunta, alguien tiene una solución más pro que me pueda recomendar

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un array de objetos, en estos objetos, la propiedad `prices` es un array, se pueden filtrar el de primer nivel, el de segundo o ambos. Si quisieras filtrar ambos se puede usar `reduce` y `filter`:

```js
const arr = [{"id":1,"name":"nombre","prices":[{"id":1,"amount":300,"end_date":"2021-10-01","start_date":"2021-10-10"},{"id":2,"amount":700,"end_date":"2021-10-11","start_date":"2021-10-15"}]},{"id":2,"name":"nombre2","prices":[{"id":3,"amount":350,"end_date":"2021-10-01","start_date":"2021-10-10"},{"id":4,"amount":750,"end_date":"2021-10-11","start_date":"2021-10-15"}]}];

const res = arr.reduce((a, c) => {

  let f = c.prices.filter(e => e.amount === 300);

  if (f.length) { 
    c.prices = f; // <-- Si existe algún elemento guardamos el array filtrado
    a.push(c);
  }

  return a;

}, []);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Super... mil gracias